# Electrical problems that get partially fixed by turning on stove

Tags: electrical

Question for electricians

NOTE TO MODS, DON'T CHANGE MY POST TITLE, THANKS.  Here is a link to the rudely closed and rudely title-changed topic I posted yesterday.
[Why is my laptop charger buzzing and my lamp dim?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/240077/why-is-my-laptop-charger-buzzing-and-my-lamp-dim)  The original title was "Question for electricians"

I posted this topic yesterday and the question is self-explanatory.  I wanted an opinion from someone experienced as an electrician to give me an idea of what is going on with the unit I am renting.  Since this situation is anomalous to me I also thought that sharing it would be of interest to electricians and engineers.  Here is the original post with the best reply to it:

I'm renting a unit on the second floor of an apartment/hotel building that has about 200-250 units. The other day I plugged my laptop computer into the electrical outlet next to my bed so I could lie on bed and surf the net. I soon heard a buzzing sound as though live electricity was leaking like a frayed wire. I turned off my fan so I could get a good lock on what was buzzing. Turns out it was the box part of my laptop charger. I quickly unplugged it and then 30 minutes later plugged it into the outlet at my desk. No buzzing at the desk.

Then last night I went to turn on my bedside lamp, a three-way lightbulb in there, and nothing on low and medium but when the third click came the lightbulb fizzled for a dim second then went out. Every cycle through the three levels results in the same dim fizzle out on the brightest setting. And then I noticed a flickering from in the kitchen as I tried to get my bedside lamp to work. Each time I reached the highest level on the lamp bulb the light above my stove flickered although it was turned off. Once I was done fiddling with the lamp I unplugged it. Then I soon discovered that the stove light is non-functional, won't turn on.

So, any electricians got a theory as to what is happening with the power in my unit?

You may also want to not plug in any more expensive electronic equipment you care about until it is fixed. Wondering if it could be a 3 phase setup and one of the phases is out resulting in a brown out / partial voltages. Had an experience at work where a phase got knocked out and all the flourescent lights started turning on and off periodically and the boards on the expensive Xerox printer were fried from the brown out conditions. –
statueuphemism
20 hours ago

Following up on this topic, I got home yesterday from work and immediately found the heater/air conditioner dysfunctional.  Where the LED temperature was supposed to be displayed the letters "br" were showing instead and the buttons were no longer lit up.  It wouldn't turn on.  So, I checked the lamp and the stove light and they were still malfunctioning.  I turned on the stovetop filament to make something to eat and right away in a second the heater returned to a functional state and the stove light turned on.

I had to wait to call management because it was still too early (I work nights), so, by the time I was able to reach someone about this strange electrical anomaly I already solved the problem; just turn on the stove and everything would start working correctly. (funny)  They were at my door in five minutes and I showed everything I explained here in this topic.  They unfortunately had no clue what was going on with the electricity and were as confounded as I was about however it could all be wired together so that turning on the stovetop affected the outlet on the opposite side of the unit and not the outlets between as well as the heater.  Her first instinct was to hit my breaker box and reset everything and obviously that didn't help.  They said that they would call an electrician and send him in as soon as possible.

Comment: There was nothing 'rude' about the sequence of events. 1. Your post title should reflect your actual issue, so it can be found by future googlers. 2. Community editing is a significant part of the Stack Exchange ethos, to improve the scope of questions or answers. You agreed to this when you signed up. 3. Your last question was closed as being too broad. You should edit to provide specifics rather than simply re-post the same question again. Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: You don't own posts on SE. You post it under a [CC-BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) license. This allows other to edit and adapt whatever you post.

Comment: Have read quite a few posts on here with your symptoms.  Most answers said to call power company for a power outage, because the person has lost the neutral phase/wire and is quite dangerous.  With an apartment an electrician might be needed since it is probably internal lost instead of an external lost with a house.

Comment: There's no need to ask the question again since it seems you've A) taken the advice offered in response to your previous question _call the landlord_, and B) the landlord is getting an electrician in ASAP to take care of the problem.

Comment: You did not solve the problem, you found the clue to find the problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: If you don't want to follow rules, go to [4chan](http://boards.4chan.org/diy/catalog). You're **here** because we are clean and filtered.  **......we're clean and filtered BECAUSE we have quality rules**.  Your other post never mentioned turning the range ON. You would have instantly gotten the correct answer.  Another rule around here is ask complete and proper questions with all relevant info.  Another is [edit] your original question don't pollute, e.g. with re-posts and meta rants. I think this is not the right forum for you.

Comment: @vidarlo also if you refuse to create an ID and reset your cookies, obliterating all evidence of authorship... who says you wrote it?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica you still accept the license when you submit the content.

Answer (score 4):

You've lost a wire of the 3 (2 hots, neutral). When you turn on the 240V stove it effectively bridges the problem and other stuff works, sort of. Problem is in your main panel or building electrical room. **Professional electrician required**.